# How to make a css animation that animates in and out by clicking

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, css-animations

I am a bit confused about how to animate in and out what I click on an element using CSS Animations.

I can get the animate in working but the animate-out for some reason does nothing. I am swapping out class names toggle the different animations, the names are toggling fine but the animate just doesn't fine.

Would really appreciate it if some one could point out my mistake for me.

Sorry I know it's a lot of code.

Here is my **SCSS**:

```
.animate-in .twitter, .animate-in .google-plus, .animate-in .facebook,
.animate-out .twitter, .animate-out .google-plus, .animate-out .facebook{
    @include animation-name(dropIn, fadeIn, dropShadow);
    @include animation-duration(500ms);
    @include animation-delay(0ms);
    @include animation-direction(alternate);
    @include animation-fill-mode(forwards);  

}
.animate-out .twitter, .animate-out .google-plus, .animate-out .facebook{
    @include animation-name(fadeOut);
    @include animation-duration(500ms);
    @include animation-delay(0ms);
    @include animation-play-state(play);
    @include animation-fill-mode(forwards);  
}
.animate-in .google-plus,
.animate-out .google-plus{
    @include animation-delay(150ms);
    @include animation-timing-function(cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1));
}
.animate-in .facebook,
.animate-out .facebook{
    @include animation-delay(400ms);
}
```

And the Keyframes:

```
$dropHeight:90px;
@include keyframes(dropIn) {
    0% {
          @include transform(  translateY(-$dropHeight) rotate(-20deg) scale(2,4) );

    } 
    100% {
      @include transform( translateY(0px) rotate(0deg) scale(1,1) );
    }
}
@include keyframes(dropShadow) {
    0% {
          @include text-shadow(-$dropHeight $dropHeight 10px rgba($darkBlue,0.2));

    } 
    100% {
      @include text-shadow(0 0 1px darken($darkBlue,3%));
    }
}
@include keyframes(fadeIn) {
    from {
      opacity:0;
    } 
    to {
      opacity:1;
    }
  }
 @include keyframes(fadeOut) {
    from {
      opacity:1;
    } 
    to {
      opacity:0;
    }
  }
```

I am using this JS to toggle the button:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('div.navbar-collapse.collapse').toggleClass('animate-out').toggleClass('animate-in');
});
```

And then Here is the HTML aswell:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
</span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse animate-out collapse" style="height: 133px;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="facebook active"><a href="#about"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"> </i><span class="text-hide">Facebook</span></a></li>
       <li class="twitter"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"> </i><span class="text-hide">Twitter</span></a></li>
       <li class="google-plus"><a href="#contact"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus"> </i><span class="text-hide">Google+</span></a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()`?

this should work without having to write all that CSS

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @n.m. mate, I was just tryng to help and that's it. I don't have sufficient reputation to make a comment. if you REALLY want me to delete or edit my answer tell me but don't scream shit to me man, thx.